# Gson: Cast Gson LinkedTreeMap to a generic ArrayList of different types

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, gson

I know similar questions have been asked here before but the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258811/gson-parse-generic-collections), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187953/deserializing-arraylist-of-non-generic-type-using-gson) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444863/google-gson-linkedtreemap-class-cast-to-myclass) really aren't helpful for me because they deal with a generic List that contains list of a single type.

I've got a POJO like the following that I parse into JSON using `Gson.toJson()`, save in my database table as a string and get it back using `Gson.fromJson()`.

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable{
    private HashMap<String, List> statistic;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void setStatistic(HashMap<String, List> statistic) {
        this.statistic = statistic;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public HashMap<String, List> getStatistic() {
        return statistic;
    }
}
```

Here is the problem. The generic `List` in the HashMap contains the following information.

```
List<ClassOne> one = new ArrayList<ClassOne>();
List<ClassTwo> two = new ArrayList<ClassTwo>();

HashMap<String, List> list = new HashMap<String, List>();
list.put("one", one);
list.put("two", two);
```

Now when I parse the JSON back to `MyClass` I get back the HashMap with the generic list. But the information about `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo` are lost and I just get the information in them as LinkedTreeMap which can't be cast to the mentioned types again by

```
MyClass myObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyClass.class);

HashMap<String, List> statistic = myObject.getStatistic();

List<ClassOne> one = (List<ClassOne>) statistic.get("one");
List<ClassTwo> one = (List<ClassTwo>) statistic.get("two");
```

How do I solve this problem? I can't change the structure of my POJO to have two ArrayLists instead of one HashMap so I'm stuck with this.